# Минимальный по размеру тип данных

Tags: c#

Eсть рандомное число. Как определить в какой минимальный по размеру тип данных помещается данное число? Первое, что приходит на ум - просто проверять меньше ли int.MaxValue и т.д., но может есть более оптимальный способ?

Comment: Возьмите от этого числа двоичный логарифм и округлите результат вверх - получите требуемое количество байт, он него и пляшите

Comment: Только не количество байт, а количество бит. Впрочем, можно взять логарифм по основанию 256.

Comment: @АндрейNOP конечно бит, опечатался немного :)

Comment: Это число существует само по себе, отдельно от всех остальных? Если чисел много, то их можно попробовать сжать каким-либо алгоритмом, в итоге потребное количество бит может сильно уменьшиться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov само по себе

Answer (score -2):

Если сделать небольшой пример, то минимальный тип данных для числа всё таки Int32, максимальный Int64.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object a = 10;

        Console.WriteLine(a + " " + checkType(a));

        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static string checkType(object val)
    {
        if (typeof(Byte).IsInstanceOfType(val))
            return "is byte";
        else if (typeof(Int16).IsInstanceOfType(val))
            return "is Int16";
        else if (typeof(Int32).IsInstanceOfType(val))
            return "is Int32";
        else if (typeof(Int64).IsInstanceOfType(val))
            return "is Int64";

        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```
10 is Int32
100000 is Int32
100000000 is Int32
10000000000 is Int64
```

Comment: `object a = 10L;` ? или `object a = 10.0;`?

Comment: @tym32167 Я имел ввиду целочисленные значения. Вы указали явно Long, а во втором случае Float или Double. Фантазия - это хорошо. Но автор заикнулся про Int.MaxValue. От этого и плясал с примером.

Comment: автор пишет про `минимальный` по размеру тип данных, вы же просто проверяете тип какого то объекта. Вы с таким успехом можете просто val.GetType().Name возвращать, где тут минимальный тип? Например, в вашем случае, для `object a = 10;` хватит и байта, но почему то вы возвращаете int

Comment: В моём случае система за меня сама решила чего хватит ей. Как оказалось Int32. Даже если указать 0x10 то она всё равно создаст объект Int32.

Comment: система за вас ничего не решает, просто по умолчанию компилятор считает число 10 типом Int32, но это никак не относится к вопросу. Вы в ответе не вычисляете ничего минимального, вы просто проверяете тип уже созданной переменной. В общем, я не люблю ставить минусы, но этому ответу поставлю, так как это ответ не только не решает задачу, но он не решает ничего в принципе.  Если я окажусь неправ и этот код действительно то, что хотел получить автор вопроса, пинганите меня, я с удовольствием пересмотрю своё мнение.

Comment: @tym32167 мне всё равно на карму. Я дал ответ так как понял вопрос.

Comment: Нисколько не сомневаюсь, сам всегда также делаю, просто если вы окажетесь правы, а я нет, я подумал, что вам будет интересно меня сюда вызвать :)